# How do I run an app in debug mode using Firebase Test Lab with App Check enabled?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check, firebase-test-lab

I am using the `patrol` package to write tests to run on devices in Firebase Test Lab. I have Firebase App Check enabled.

App Check is working for release builds, and in debug mode when adding a token that was printed to the console to the token list in the Firebase console.

When running tests in Test Lab, how can I manually set an App Check token that was generated in the Firebase console, so that the apps can run with proper App Check attestation while in the Test Lab environment on a debug build? There is no clear way in the docs for flutter to manually set a debug App Check token.